# Remove browser autocompletion in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am currently trying to remove the form autocompletion done by the user's browser which can cause some critical behavior since it fills the password field. I have already added the autocompletion attribute to all of my textbox fields but when I try with firefox it stills load my current login information into the fields.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

EDIT: Since it's not clear, I have already added the aucompletion attribute with the value set to "off".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an `autocomplete=off` property in html.

It is used in the top right search box on this very page, inspect the html you'll see:

```
<input autocomplete=​"off" name=​"q" class=​"textbox" placeholder=​"search" ..... />
```

See this MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

In MVC you would implement this at the form or for a textbox like so:

```
Html.BeginForm(
    action, controller, FormMethod.Post, new {autocomplete="off"})
```

OR

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployerNumber, new {autocomplete="off"})
```

Comment: Adding to the form can sometimes help if adding to the inputs doesn't work (looking at you, IE)

Answer (score 1):

If you check [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion#How_to_Turn_Off_the_Autocompletion_Feature), setting `autocomplete="off"` on the form should do the trick.

Comment: If you inspect the StackOverflow search box you will see they achieved this in the same way.

Comment: `<div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HashedPassword, new { autocomplete = "off" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HashedPassword)
            </div>` 

I already set the autocompletion attribute to off, but when i check my html source code it doesn't had the attribute in the input markdown.

Comment: @Oflocet you should actually use `autocomplete` where you render the input or form not at the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can randomize id and name attributes of your textboxes - this will make browser autocomplete functions not working.

My implementation

In view:

```
<%
    var guidString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
%>
<%=Html.TextBox(guidString, String.Empty)%>
<%=Html.Hidden("NameGuid", guidString) %>
```

in Controller:

```
string userName = Request[model.NameGuid];
...
```

Comment: Wow, you've been fast! I was just adding the same answer!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 have a add-on syntax for form/input elements, it is called autocomplete="off".
See http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_form_autocomplete.asp