# autocomplete=off not working in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying not to generate autocomplete in browser for that I am trying this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
model => model.UserName, 
new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

which generate HTML like this

```
<input type="text" value="" name="UserName" id="UserName" data-val-required="User name is required." data-val="true" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

In other views I have use the same and it is working fine. but in login view `autocomplete="off"` not working. for doing so I have clear model state like this in controller

```
 ModelState.Remove("UserName");
```

reference taken from the following sites

- [How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)
- [Disable autocomplete on html helper textbox in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274407/disable-autocomplete-on-html-helper-textbox-in-mvc)
- [How to disable autocomplete in MVC Html Helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015803/how-to-disable-autocomplete-in-mvc-html-helper)
- [Remove browser autocompletion in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427852/remove-browser-autocompletion-in-mvc)

I still wonder what is wrong in my code? Your suggestion means a lot to me.

Answer (score 7):

As per Bharat's answer it actually, the issue is not of the autocomplete,
the issue comes from the browser's saved logins.

but we can overcome this without going to clear saved passwords of the browser.
As per my intention, all browsers doing similar duties that the field before the password is assumed as Username and it uses the last logged in data will be pasted automatically even if we do `autocomplete="off"`.

The solution is to make the password's field `autocomplete="new-password"`, but this will work only in HTML5 or above supported browsers only...

Answer (score 1):

It is Working in MVC 5, to auto-complete off

```cs
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, 
  new { @placeholder = "UserName", @id = "txtUserName", @autocomplete = "new-user" })

@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, 
  new {@placeholder = "Password", @id = "txtPassword", @autocomplete = "new-password" })
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the browser's saved logins.
When these issue arise at my side, i removed saved logins from my browser and it solved my issue.

visit https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/962690
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en